# What is the best filesystem for KVM?

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

What is the best filesystem for KVM Hypervisor?

`raw + VirtIO` or `qcow2 + VirtIO` ?

Performance is the main issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

raw + virtio provides slightly better performance, but it lacks the snapshot ability. None of these is actually a filesystem, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, and which caching method do you suggest? writeback, writethrough or none ?

Comment: none is fine if you have cache in the disks and the controller

Comment: I actually didn't set any cache in the disks. and what is controller? Thanks

Comment: and my last issue: is there much difference between qcow2 without virtio and raw+virtio? Thanks

Comment: controller is the SCSI card that your disks/disk backplane are connected to. In normal servers it has it's own cache and battery. as for with or without virtio - always go _with_ for better performance.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: this kind of question arises quite often, since these things are really poorly documented, so I don’t find tihs question bad...

Comment: This kind of question is wrong, because the real answer here would be "it depends"